# flutter packages get failed depends on flutter_test any from sdk which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed

Tags: sdk, flutter, package

I create a flutter project, and run flutter packeages get,the output as below:
[second] flutter packages get
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Running "flutter packages get" in second...
The current Dart SDK version is `2.0.0-dev.63.0.flutter-4c9689c1d2`.

```
Because second depends on flutter_test any from sdk which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
exit code 1
```

`flutter doctor -v`

```
PS D:\dartstudy\second> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, v0.5.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 0.5.7 at E:\flutter
    • Framework revision 66091f9696 (2 weeks ago), 2018-07-09 12:52:41 -0700
    • Engine revision 6fe748490d
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.63.0.flutter-4c9689c1d2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.1)
    • Android SDK at f:\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.1
    • ANDROID_HOME = f:\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 26.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.25.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.16.0

[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

the IDE that I use to create a project is VS code.
I changed some versions of flutter sdk， the problems are the same as above，How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 23):

I was having a similar issue:

```
Running "flutter packages get" in austin-feeds-me-flutter...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760.

Because austin_feeds_me depends on palette_generator any which requires SDK version >=2.0.0-dev.61.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I fixed it with the following commands:

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
```

Fix source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19382

Comment: For channel, Flutter recommend using the stablebranch. see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels

Comment: This worked for me after I reinstalled my os and wanted to reopen an old flutter app.

Comment: I would not consider going to the dev channel as a valid solution for stable projects

Comment: @RideSun that is a good warning. Please use this answer with discretion.

Comment: Currently, if you use this answer, you have to  run "flutter channel beta" instead of "flutter channel dev", because dev channel is deprecated. Hope It helps someone.

Answer (score 9):

I solved my error by using `any` instead of the version codes like this

```
flutter_test: any
```

instead of

```
flutter_test: ^1.1.0+1
```

Comment: I like this option, but with a small twist.   The normal project skeleton has flutter_test coming from the SDK, so I used 'any' for test (non-widget testing) to avoid the version conflicts.

Answer (score 6):

just update your sdk by these codes

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
```

if you live in iran you need to use proxy because google no let you to use its packages
and for scoped_model you need to use below version of it in your pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
```

and then save the file, your IDE automatically update the package

Comment: I got this error after that "Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2."

Answer (score 2):

Just modify the package version in pubspec.yaml to the latest version fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an outdated question but I think someone will benefit from this and also the answer is relevant not outdated.

You need to fix `environment:` in `pubspec.yaml` to allow the Dart SDK version you are using (the one from Flutter)

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
```

The essential part is `<3.0.0`

Originally answered here in GitHub by someone called Günter Zöchbauer:- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21421#issuecomment-418718539

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade flutter to the latest version. This solved the problem for me.

flutter upgrade //for upgrading flutter enter this in CLI.

Comment: While this answers the question, it just repeats information that is already provided in previous answers. When you have enough reputation, you can upvote the useful answer(s) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this question by myself.I add the system environment variable PUB_ALLOW_PRERELEASE_SDK=false,so Just remove this  system environment variable, the question will be solved.

Comment: I don't have that environment variable when doing "env", but still have that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and `flutter upgrade --force` fixed the problem.

Note: re-run the command `flutter pub get` after upgrading your flutter version.

Answer (score 0):

So here are some options to consider in solving this issue:

If you have tried the above solutions and it didn't work, then

1. You probably have issues with your flutter SDK and need to fix that first. `You have changes in your flutter SDK`.

To fix this, kindly cd into your flutter directory. For instance D:\repo\flutter
Find out what git changes you have in this directory using `git status`

Use `git add *` to add these changes (files) and then do `git stash`

To ensure that you're on the latest build from this channel, run `flutter upgrade`

You should be able to switch to any of your flutter channels

Stay safe. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Flutter SDK is not in the latest version. upgrade it by below command (and the documentation says, it is preferred to keep stable channel, upgrade to dev only if it essential)

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by adding `integration_test` above test declaration, I saw this solution in official codelabs: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-app-testing#2

As on pic:

[image: screenshot]

I think this is a better way, than downgrading the plugin by using 'any' or changing flutter channel.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing geoflutterfire: ^3.0.3 to geoflutterfire2: ^2.3.15, it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

Inspect correctly your "pubspect.yaml" it's possible

Comment: What is possible?